# Limit of display in vb6

Tags: vb6

Do we have any limitation in displaying the no. of records in VB6?
Like if the no. of records exceeds the size of long,then will it create problem?

Comment: what type of control is used for displaying records and what classes are used for data access (ADO Recordsets or DAO, or RDO Resultsets or something else?

Comment: Good questions... but yes, since VB6 is 32-bit, if the number of records exceeds 2,147,4873,647 you are likely to encounter problems no matter what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: real answer** - VB6 is a 32-bit programming system and therefore can store numbers up to 2,147,483,647 when declared as type Long. The "facts" below were obviously ironic. Sheesh, you guys are humorless crabapples :)

VB6 facts:

- VB6 is only allowed to process 10
  records at a time. If any of the data
  contains "{" or "}" or ";", VB6 will
  shut down. This is by design, it has
  to make way for a "real" programming
  language.
- VB6 alters your DNA to make your
  future children bad programmers. It
  has already traveled into the past to
  ensure you will be a shitty
  programmer (that's why you're using
  it now).
- Windows has a built-in speed limit on
  VB6 programs. They are never allowed
  to be fast enough to solve an actual
  business problem.
- 32-bit integers in VB6 are actually
  31-bit.
- VB6 is not just obsolete, it's
  actually illegal (check with
  Interpol)
- If you added up all the keystrokes
  saved by not typing "Then" in C#, you
  would have exactly enough to make
  this post.

Comment: I thought it was funny... and I still have to program in VB6 (and for some reason VB.net)... oh C# how I miss thee.

Comment: +1. Too bad your VB6 only goes up to 10 records though. Mine goes up to 11 ;)